# How Can i Create Order for bundle product in Magento2.4.6 Programatically

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, magento2.4.6, create-order

I have a requirement In Magento 2.4.6 to create an order with bundle product Programatically. here i need to add selected bundle option along with related product while creating order, can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this below code with the order data as (API Body)

> {
> "orderData": {
> "currency_id": "USD",
> "email": "test@test.com",
> "shipping_address":
> {
> "firstname": "john",
> "lastname": "doe",
> "street": "xxxx",
> "city": "xxxx",
> "country_id": "MY",
> "region": "xxxx",
> "postcode": "4324",
> "telephone": "523432",
> "fax": "32423",
> "save_in_address_book": 1
> },
> "items": [
> {
> "product_id": "8",
> "qty": 2,
> "price": 10
> },
> {
> "product_id": "12",
> "qty": 1,
> "sku": "bundle-product-1",
> "bundle_options":{
> "3" : "5", // 3 is option id and 5 is selected id (not product id)
> "4": "7"
> }
> }
> ]
> }
> }

```
  public function createOrder($orderData)
 {
     try {
         // $this->validateOrderData($orderData);
         foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
             if (isset($item['bundle_options'])) {
                 $product = $this->productRepository->getById($item['product_id']);
                 $params = [
                     'product' => 12,
                     'bundle_option' => $item['bundle_options'],
                     'qty' => $item['qty']
                 ];
                 $this->cart->addProduct($product,$params);
             }
             $cart = $this->cart->save();
             $quoteId = $cart->getQuote()->getId();
         }
         $store=$this->storeManager->getStore();
         $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
         $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
         $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
         $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);
         if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
             $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                     ->setStore($store)
                     ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                     ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                     ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                     ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
             $customer->save();
         }
         $quote=$this->quote->create()->load($quoteId);
         $quote->setStore($store);
         $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
         $quote->setCurrency();
         $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
         
         foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
             if (!isset($item['bundle_options'])) {
                 $product=$this->product->load($item['product_id']);
                 $product->setPrice($item['price']);
                 $quote->addProduct(
                     $product,
                     intval($item['qty'])
                 );
             }
         }
         
         // Set addresses
         $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
         $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);

         // Shipment mwthod and rates
         $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
         $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                         ->collectShippingRates()
                         ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');

         // Payment method dummy Credit memo
         $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
         $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
         $quote->save();
         $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

         // Collect Totals & Save Quote
         $quote->collectTotals()->save();
         // Create Order From Quote
         $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
         $order->setStatus(OrderStatus::PAYMENT_INITIATED);
         $order->setEmailSent(0);
         $order->save();

         $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
         if($order->getEntityId()){
             $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
         }else{
             $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
         }
         return $result;
     } catch (\Exception $e) {
         throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Could not save order: %1', $e->getMessage()));
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy It's Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code and change your option id as per your current id.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Load necessary classes
$quoteFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
$orderService = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$customerRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface');
$customer = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->create()->load(1);

// Load bundle product by SKU
$productSku = 'your_bundle_product_sku';
$product = $productRepository->get($productSku);

// Create new quote
$quote = $quoteFactory->create();
$quote->setStore($objectManager->getStore());

// Add customer to the quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);

// Add bundle product to the quote
$quote->addProduct($product);

// Set bundle options
$options = [
    'bundle_option' => [
        // Enter your bundle option ids and selection ids here
        // Example: 
        // '1' => ['1' => '5'],
        // '2' => ['2' => '10'],
        // ...
    ],
    'bundle_option_qty' => [
        // Enter quantity for each bundle option here
        // Example:
        // '1' => 1,
        // '2' => 2,
        // ...
    ]
];
$quote->addData($options);

$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getData());
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getData());

// Collect totals
$quote->collectTotals();

// Submit the quote and create the order
$order = $orderService->prepare($quote);
$order->setCustomerId($quote->getCustomerId());
$order->setCustomerEmail($quote->getCustomerEmail());
$order->setCustomerIsGuest(0);
$order->setCustomerGroupId($quote->getCustomerGroupId());
$order->setStoreId($quote->getStoreId());
$order->setCurrency();
$order->setSubtotal($quote->getSubtotal());
$order->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal());
$order->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal());
$order->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal());

$order->save();
$order->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
$order->setState("new")->setStatus("pending");
$order->save();

echo "Order created successfully. Order ID: " . $order->getId();
```

Let me know if any queries.

**`Thank your`**